# Glide cannot show image URL in Dialog Listview item ImageView item

Tags: android, android-listview, android-glide, custom-adapter, listview-adapter

Show list of Guard in `ListView` with Image.

Used `Target`, `ImageViewTarget`, and `DrawableImageViewTarget` but all not working

Show `ListView` in Dialog

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(CameraActivityForCheckInOut.this);    
dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_list);
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));    
btnCloseDialog = dialog.findViewById(R.id.close_button);
listViewDialog = dialog.findViewById(R.id.list);    
btnCloseDialog.setOnClickListener(v -> {
stopAudio();
resumeFaceRecognition();
});    
Adapter adapter = new adapter(list);
listViewDialog.setAdapter(adapter);
setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(listViewDialog);
dialog.setCancelable(false);
dialog.show();
```

ListView Adapter's `getView()`:

```
    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
            final ViewHolder holder;
            if (view == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
                holder.imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.Image);
                view.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            }
            try {
                Person person = persons.get(position);
                try {
                    String url = person.getProfileURL();

 Glide.with(activity).load(url).centerCrop().placeholder(R.mipmap.person).fallback(R.mipmap.person).error(R.mipmap.person).into(holder.imageView);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }   
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return view;
        }
```

show image in `listview` item `ImageView`

Comment: I think you need more in your question. Ask something specific.

Comment: replace e.printStackTrace() with Log.e(e) .... check your logcat and post the exception you get

Comment: Glide.with(activity).load(url).centerCrop().placeholder(R.mipmap.person).fallback(R.mipmap.person).error(R.mipmap.person).into(holder.imageView); throws illigalArgumentException

Comment: Make sure your `url` has some data. It should not empty.

Comment: URL is not empty checked

Comment: post the illegal argument exception stack trace in the question please

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must call this method on the main thread
        at com.bumptech.glide.util.Util.assertMainThread(Util.java:142)
        at com.bumptech.glide.RequestBuilder.into(RequestBuilder.java:684)

Comment: Which version of Glide are you using?

Comment: Glide version is 4.9.0

Comment: If your are calling the method on background threads you have to use `Glide.with(context).load(url).into(new Target<Bitmap>() {
    ...
  });`

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I also tried Target<Bitmap>.....It's not working